# Can't import functions/modules

Tags: python, import, module

I'm simply trying to import a function from another script. But despite `import` running successfully, the functions never enter my local environment.

The paths and files look like this:

`project/__main__.py`

`project/script_a.py`

```
from setup import script_b
x = ABC() # NameError: name 'ABC' is not defined
print(x)
```

`project/setup/__init__.py`

`project/setup/script_b.py`

```
def ABC():
    return "ABC"
```

I've done this before and the documentation (officials and on here) is quite straightforward but I cannot grasp what I am failing to understand. Is the function running but never entering my environment?

---

I also tried using...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def ABC():
        return "ABC"
```

...as script_b.

Comment: Import the functions inside the module `from setup.script_b import ABC`

Comment: Or ``x = script_b.ABC()``

Comment: @Peterrabbit There was an issue with my IDE not accepting from `setup.script_b import ABC` while showing me the correct path (driving me mad). I deleted the environment and started again. I wouldn't have thought to do this without the help. If you submit this as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the functions inside the module:

```py
from setup.script_b import ABC
```

Or call the function on the modules name like said in the comments

```py
x = script_b.ABC()
```